# Giving high-rep users' questions more time on the front page

Tags: discussion, homepage

I've given 500 answers in the past couple months, but when I ask the rare question it gets knocked off the front page just as quickly as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179736/timex) who's posted 888 questions and only 52 answers.

How about giving giving a little back to those who mostly help others by adding weight to their questions when deciding which ones to list on the home page? Chances are a user like this will ask higher quality questions, as he/she has a better sense of what readers will look for.

Thoughts on this?

Comment: I have considered the bounty system, but this request would have a more immediate effect.

Comment: 888/52 is not that bad, [really](http://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman) ;-) ([Source](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/661/reputation-from-questions) on the Data Explorer.)

Comment: @Arjan I never meant to suggest it was bad. I was suggesting a rare questioner who gives a lot to this site be rewarded with more help in return when he does ask. But as Pekka points out, we indirectly get this without tweaks to the ranking system.

Comment: It's not a bad idea.  I vote we should get 5% more time than normal, so instead of the 32 seconds of front page time regular posts get, we get 33 seconds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can relate (having [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855782/vertical-tab-component-on-jquery-ui-site) right this moment), but such preferential treatment of high-rep users wouldn't feel right. I think the bounty system is enough to create attention if your question really doesn't go anywhere.

Plus in general, in my experience, there is already a lot of readiness to go the extra mile to help out a high-rep user.

Comment: Your last statement is very true.

Comment: couldn't agree more! nicely put!

Answer (score 4):

I completely disagree with the idea.

Why? because it goes against the democracy in SO.

Every user should get the same chance of his question being answered, the only difference should be in the quality of the questions, regardless of the user: better questions => more attention.

Other than later, nothing should change.

90% of the traffic to StackOverflow comes from Google, new users and anonymous ones, are as important to this site as as heavy question answerers.

The user you point out, has a high percent acceptance rate, and questions that get frequently up-voted and has earned himself a reasonable reputation.

You privilege for answering questions, you get the double of point per up-vote (not a minor one).

This is a **Q**&A site, let's welcome good questions from any user, not any question from good users.

Comment: Re-reading If I was to harsh sorry, I mean all in the best of intentions.

Comment: No, you're right. It takes many bad ideas before you come up with a good idea. I admit this was a bad one.

Comment: @marcog as for bad ideas, believe me I've seen worse :) the intentions were good and your re-considering of the idea is admiramble that's what counts! And what you say is very true, how are you going to get the good ideas if you don't discard the bad one.

Answer (score 2):

Weighting the questions like this presents a bias towards higher-rep users. There are a variety of sorting and filtering options available that will allow people to only see new questions they want to see. The home page is not the only frontier.

Comment: How often does SO receive a question from a user with >500 answers and a >25:1 answer:question ratio? Yes it will bias towards higher-rep users (that's the point), but I don't think it will have a huge overall impact. And at least the home page is *one way*. It is the most intelligent filter already.

Comment: @marcog: I follow a specific set of RSS tag feeds and completely ignore the home page. Even with weighting the home page would turn over far to quickly to matter.