# Some reputation which yields "escalate (BUMP) the question!"

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add a way to 'bump' questions back to the front page.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/please-add-a-way-to-bump-questions-back-to-the-front-page)

In a crowded tags listing, its a matter of minutes that your question is buried under number of comments.

Essentially, there must be a role designed for the users to have the ability to BUMP the questions so it is raised back to top marked with "bump +1 [2, 3......]" in order to draw the crowd's attention. Besides their own questions, the user with this role may also be able to uplift other member's questions.

Comment: ops, i never looked at that question before you mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like you're asking for users to have the ability to bump questions for very subjective reasons, possibly without putting more effort into the question.

There are already mechanisms in place to get attention to a question. If you edit the question (and, one would hope, improve it), or consider answering it, it brings it to the rop of the list. You can also place a bounty to get attention to the question.

You could also bring the question up in chat, and ask what to do to the question to get more answers.

Comment: @gbn - Whoops; meant to get back to that. Thanks.

Comment: Well, this answer would suffice my curiosity about; how to make my question noticed and get maximum replies.

Answer (score 11):

We already have this in multiple incarnations:

1. **You can edit (or suggest an edit) to the question.** Considering how incredibly rare it is to come across a post that is *perfect* and cannot be improved in any possible way, this is often the best and easiest solution. Any time that a question is edited, it is automatically "bumped" to the top of the list.
2. **You can set a bounty on the question.** This does require [a trivial amount of reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), and it does entail you giving up some of your *own* hard-earned reputation, but if the question is about something that is really important to you, neither of these should be insurmountable burdens. The bounty system was explicitly designed to "bump" questions so that they're seen by more people, and thus [hopefully] answered more quickly. They even appear under the special "featured" tab, where they'll remain for much longer and are very unlikely to get "bumped off" by other questions.
3. **You can answer the question.** This isn't always a workable solution, particularly for questions which you don't know the answer. And we strongly discourage users from posting answers to questions that don't actually, well, *answer* the question. But if you can contribute something useful, this is an appropriate way of "bumping" the question back up to the top of the list.
4. **The [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) already bumps old questions in need of attention.** I don't believe that the *exact* algorithm has been published, but this *does* work for questions that have been around for a while but haven't received any answers.

And it's been proposed that we [give high-rep users' questions more time on the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77280/giving-high-rep-users-questions-more-time-on-the-front-page). You can show your support for that proposal by voting for it, if you wish.